# How to get parent module/package functions in namespace of child package/module in Python?

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces, package

I have an extremely complicated module and I want to break out the subpackages into individual packages.   My first attempt will be for the "utilities" submodule. I want to be able to import everything from the parent package `example_utils.py` into `example_module.utils` but I also want `example_module.utils` to have it's own functions as well.

**In the end I want to be able to do the following:**

```
import example_module as em
x = 10
y1 = em.utils.f_parent1(x)
y2 = em.utils.f_child1(x)

# and do this 
from example_module.utils import f_parent1, f_child1

# and use the parent module as a standalone
from example_utils import f_parent1, f_parent2
```

#### How can I structure my child module `example_module` to have this functionality?**

**Module utilities saved as separate standalone module `example_utils.py`**

```
def f_parent1(x):
    return x

def f_parent2(x,y):
    return x+y
```

This module will be installed in my environment:

```
pip install path/to/example_module
```

**Larger module (`example_module`) using `example_utils` as a dependency**

```
# Directory structure for larger Module

example_module
|++++| __init__.py
|++++| utils  
|++++| ++++ | __init__.py
|++++| ++++ | utils.py
```

**Contents of `|++++| ++++ | __init__.py`**

```
from .utils import *
```

**Contents of `|++++| ++++ | utils.py`**

```
from example_utils import * 

def f_child1(x):
    return x**2
```

**Contents of `|++++| __init__.py`**

```
__version__= "0.1"
__developmental__ = True

# Utilities
from .utils import utils

# =======
# Direct Exports
# =======
_submodules = ["utils"]
__all__ = sorted(__all__)
```

Apologies in advance if `namespace` is not the correct term.  I get confused with `namespace`, `scope`, etc.

Comment: `f_parent1` is really the same function across both modules, since they're referencing the same thing.  So even giving `f_parent1` a different name would serve no purpose other than creating an extra reference.

Comment: I understand but I want to make it backwards compatible with my old notebooks.

Comment: If that's the case, would `from example_module.utils import f_parent1 as em_f_parent1; from example_utils import as eu_f_parent1` solve your problem? Otherwise I'm not too sure I understand the ask.  If you need a separate reference between the parent and child they can't *both* be `f_parent1`.

Comment: Hmm... I see what you're saying.  The reason why I'm trying to load the parent module into the name space of the child module is because I have thousands of lines of code that I would need to sift through to fix these errors.  I can work some magic in the imports but I'd really like to have this functionality if possible.  Even if this isn't the best way to approach this situation, do you know how to make this possible?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused.  Maybe if you could provide a use case where `f_parent1` needs to be distinctly different between the parent and child then it'd help.  Meanwhile, another way is to refer to the functions like this: `import module1 as m1, module2 as m2` and then refer the functions by `func = 'f_parent1'; getattr(m1, func); getattr(m2, func)`.  The proper way would be to just use `m1.f_parent1` or `m2.f_parent1` but if you *need* to reference the function with one name, that's one way to do it.

Comment: That's a great idea!  Import the parent module and then set an alias with setattr.

Comment: I find that would be a messier approach but if it works for you, that's great.  I don't think I understand fully your struggle so I'll simply wish you good luck.  Hopefully others can weigh in as well.

Comment: To be specific, I've created this package: https://github.com/jolespin/soothsayer but it's a mess to install.  I want to be able to use bits of code in other environments that is not dependent on the entire suite.  I then made this package https://github.com/jolespin/soothsayer_utils which has most of the fundamental code from soothsayer.utils .  Now I can install soothsayer_utils in all of my environmnts and use the light weight code.  Then in my main environment use it from soothsayer.  I agree it's not the cleanest but it'll make maintenance easier downstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With suggestions from @r-ook  I found that I could use `getattr` to grab the function by string name from the parent module.  After that, I could add the function into the namespace?scope? of the child module.

example.py

```
from example_utils import as emu


functions_from_parent = ["f_parent1", "f_parent2"]

__all__ = {"f_child1"}

for function_name in functions_from_parent:
    globals()[function_name] = getattr(emu, function_name)
    __all__.add(function_name)
__all__ = sorted(__all__)

def f_child1(x):
    return x**2
```